# bytes and strings python

Tags: python, string, byte

```
encoding = ('utf-8')
data = b"C:\Users\victim\Desktop\test1.exe"
print (data.decode(encoding))
```

when I run it I get the following 
C:\Users[]ictim\Desktop est1.exe
what I need to get is C:\Users\victim\Desktop\test1.exe

Comment: change to data to \\ instead of \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to escape the `\` characters, otherwise it'll pick up on the character next to it and take it as a `\t`. Try:

```
>>> encoding = ('utf-8')
>>> data = b"C:\\Users\\victim\\Desktop\\test1.exe"
>>> print (data.decode(encoding))
C:\Users\victim\Desktop\test1.exe
```

Alternatively, skip the encoding part, and just define your string as raw:

```
data = r"C:\Users\victim\Desktop\test1.exe"
```